# WebView doesn't scroll when keyboard opened

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I have a WebView that contains an input form.
When the user selects the first input the keyboard appears and will scroll the WebView so that the input is uncovered. My problem is in < API 19 when tapping on the next partially obscured input the WebView doesn't scroll. If I were to close the keyboard and then select the input it would scroll correctly.

I've read a lot about if the Activity is FullScreen then it won't work but my app isn't.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.MyApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.MyApp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

WebView Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/banking_webview"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/BannerOrange"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/banner_image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/single_line_height"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/typography_subhead"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.app.MyApp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

to you root of the layout file for the fragment/activity as well as:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to you activity in the manifest.

Comment: THIS WORKED! Finally! I spent half a day on this problem. I feel like I need a drink to celebrate

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your WebView tag in layout xml.