# Android keyboard hide input webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, pan

The webview is not pushed up when the input field is focused. I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest and the view is not in fullscreen mode. The input field is always hidden by the keyboard. Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279364/android-webview-doesnt-scroll-enough-when-keyboard-opens

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wb.requestFocusFromTouch();
wb.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: @CoperAnswald The problem is that webview isn't getting focus when it is load, see my edited answer.

Comment: the problem persist, when the input is focused the keyboard open

Comment: @CoperAnswald I think I had missed something, Is your problem to not showing keyboard when the Input has touched? or not?

Comment: no, the problem is that the webview content is not pushed up when the keyboard is visible so the input field is behind

Comment: @CoperAnswald Oh! you must try adjustPan instead of adjustResize in Manifest.

Comment: I don't think so